# How to create a multi column index with descending option

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table foo (id, name, col1, col2, col3, ..);
create index index_name on foo (col1, col2, col3 desc);
```

How do I know if it has been created in the descending option and how to verify if queries on foo are really using this index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create a multi column index with descending option.

The `DESC` is parsed but ignored.

From MySQL Docs: **[`CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html)** syntax:

> An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but **ignored**; index values are **always stored in ascending order**.

As for seeing what index is used in queries, you should look into the **[`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html)** statement which makes it easy to see which indices are used in a particular query.

Comment: Eh, you beat me to quoting the same lines in the manual :) I'll remove my answer but you may want to add a link to EXPLAIN too.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: thnx, I missed that part of the question.

Comment: We are currently using 5.1.57 and we have plans to migrate to 5.5.12 in a AWS RDS environment. Does it mean this will not be supported in the latest versions of MySQL too?

Comment: The link is for 5.6 documentation. If Oracle has plans to add this feature (and when), I wouldn't have a clue.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL now supports multi-column descending indices](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html) c. MySQL 8.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).